# Raspberry pi has ip address, not connecting to internet

Tags: raspbian, internet, static-ip, iptables, jessie-lite

I have my raspberry pi running on raspbian jessie lite. I have created a hotspot on my windows machine and connected my raspberry pi to the hotspot. The pi has got an ip address assigned to it, but when I ping www.google.com I get **unknown host**, and when I ping 8.8.8.8 I get **network is unreachable**.

I tried connecting my phone to the wifi hotspot and it got connected to the internet. 
The hotspot shows that both my phone and raspberry pi is connected to the PC but the raspberrt pi is not connecting to the internet, while my phone is working fine.

**ifconfig:**

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:ae:1a:8a
>
> ```
>       inet6 addr: fe80::3a87:90a8:b2e7:b84a/64 Scope:Link
>       UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>       RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>       TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>       RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
> ```
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>
> ```
>       inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>       inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>       RX packets:340 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>       TX packets:340 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
>       RX bytes:27440 (26.7 KiB)  TX bytes:27440 (26.7 KiB)
> ```
>
> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:2b:73:ec:0d:12
>
> ```
>       inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>       inet6 addr: fe80::64f1:6e14:507d:7cb7/64 Scope:Link
>       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>       RX packets:808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>       TX packets:540 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>       RX bytes:80924 (79.0 KiB)  TX bytes:87654 (85.5 KiB)
> ```

**route:**

> Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask
>
> Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface link-local      *
>
> 255.255.0.0     U     303    0        0 wlan0
>   192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0

I work on embedded systems ,this linux and networking just makes me mad.

Comment: As you have not told us how you configured the Pi any answer is speculative. The problem is more likely to be configuration of Windows.

Comment: @Milliways I used a opensource hotspot creator for windows. I checked and  it was working fine with my mobile.

Comment: Ping following: <br> 1. gateway<br> 2. WAN interface of gateway <br> 3. gateway of gateway.<br> and tell us the result.

Comment: @Sean83 I'm not sure which is the gateway in my system(windows). I tired looking up all the device ip in my system. I'm not able to find out what  my ip is. I tend to get ip under wireless lan adapter, ppp adapter, and ethernet adapter. My pc is connected to the isp through pppoe and the created hotspot shares this connection over wifi. Which one should I ping

Comment: @Sean83 If I'm right this is my gateway _itallic_PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.57 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=1.25 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=1.15 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=1.14 ms
^X64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=1.16 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=1.19 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=1.16 ms
_italic_

Comment: @Sean83 I somehow copied the ips from the hotspot config and added to the pi, it works now. thanks. I'm yet to restart the whole system to see I have to reconfigure the gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At minimum, you need to add a default gateway:

```
route add default gw <IP of gateway device>
```

The IP will be the IP address of the hotspot.

To resolve names to IP addresses, you'll need to add at least one DNS server:

```
echo "nameserver <IP of DNS server>" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

The IP here will be that of your DNS server (quite possibly the same IP as the gateway above, but that's not certain as I don't know your network).

Comment: The default gateway and nameserver gets reset(deleted) after reboot. any workarounds?

Comment: Add dns-nameservers to /etc/network/interfaces, Ref. : https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration